# Linear then Log ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I'm looking to make an x axis which looks like this:

[image]

i.e. it is linear for values below $0$ but then goes as a $log$

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x + y^2]}, {x, -30, 30, 0.3}, {y, 0, 30, 0.3}], 1];
```

I can make a linear plot

```
ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

[image]

I can make a log plot. But how do I combine them?

```
ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {0, 25}, {-1, 1}}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Linear", "Linear"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Transform your data so it remains linear for x<0 and is log for x>0. Then you don't need to combine anything. `newdata=Map[If[#[[1]]>0,{Log[#[[1]]],#[[2]],#[[3]]},#]&,data];
ListDensityPlot[newdata,...]` All you have to do now is create your own ticks along the x axis to look like what you want. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom scaling function:

```
threshold = 10^-4;
scalingF = If[# < threshold, #, threshold + Log[  #/threshold]] &;
invscalingF = InverseFunction[scalingF];

ListDensityPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {0, 25}, {-1, 1}}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{scalingF, invscalingF}, "Linear", "Linear"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From Bills comment, I get a satisfactory result

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, Sin[x + y^2]}, {x, 0, 3000, 100}, {y, 0, 30, 0.3}], 1];
data2 = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, Sin[x + y^2]}, {x, -30, 0, 0.1}, {y, 0, 30, 0.3}], 
   1];
data = Join[data, data2];

newdata = 
  Map[If[#[[1]] > 0, {Log[#[[1]]], #[[2]], #[[3]]}, #] &, data];

x = {#, ToString[#]} & /@ {0, -5, -10};
x2 = {N[Log[#]], ToString[#]} & /@ {10, 100, 1000};
y = {#, ToString[#]} & /@ Range[0, 30, 10];
ticks = {{y, None}, Join[x, x2]}

ListDensityPlot[newdata, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, Log[3000]}, {0, 30}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> ticks]
```

[image]